Maximizing a semi-concave function
A function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ is called semi-concave if $x\rightarrow f(x)-\frac{\lambda}{2}\|x\|^2$ is concave for some $\lambda>0$.
Suppose I want to maximize a function $f$ which is not concave but is semi-concave. Is this a well-studied problem? Are there any results or algorithms about this? Thank you!

$-f$ is called a "weakly convex function". Here is a reference on an algorithm and analysis for this class of problems. You can find more relevant references by checking out related papers on Google Scholar.

Stochastic Subgradient Method Converges at the Rate O(k − 1/4) on Weakly Convex Functions (Just gave a name to the link by @ProAmateur).
